# Asking user input from the controller in MVP application

Tags: java, swing, mvp

I'm trying to implement the MVP pattern in my Java application, a simple board game. 
This is roughly the structure of my project:

1- Model: Game class that contains the state of the game (players, position on the board etc)

2- Controller/Presenter: GameController class contains all the logic of the game, it operates the different phases of the game and interacts with the model and the View interface

3- ViewInterface: it's the interface that the controller uses to interact with the user

4- View: the view that directly interacts with user, implements the ViewInterface methods

The main problem I have is that during the game I have to ask the user the value for something so in my controller I simply write

```
int valueINeed = viewInterface.getValue();
```

and this approach works perfectly if the view is the text based (i.e. console input), but I'm trying to implement an interface using swing and doing so blocks my UI. So what's the correct way to ask the user input?

Comment: `GameController class contains all the logic of the game` this is not ok

Comment: Cause business logic should be in `Model`